# Обход бинарного дерева без рекурсии

Tags: php

Помогите, два дня уже мучаюсь, не пойму как перебрать дерево: с неограниченным числом вложений, без рекурсии и без ООП. Просто циклами. У кого есть алгоритм, напишите пожалуйста.

```
  $massive[2]["id"] = 2;
          $parentNosology[] = 2;
          $childNosology = [];
          while($childNosology != NULL){
            foreach($parentNosology as $keyNosology => $valueNosology){
              $childNosology[] = $this->cicleFree($valueNosology);

              $massive[$valueNosology]["children"] = $childNosology[0];
            }
            unset($parentNosology);
            foreach($childNosology as $keyChild => $valueChild){
              foreach($valueChild as $k => $v){
                if($v["id"] != NULL)
                $parentNosology[] = $v["id"];
              }
            }
            unset($childNosology);
          }

public function cicleFree($nosologyMassive)
    {
            $nosologyParent = $this->_database->query("SELECT `code` FROM `md_nosology` WHERE `parent_code` = ".$nosologyMassive);
            foreach ($nosologyParent as $key => $value) {
                $allNosolog[$value["code"]]["id"] = $value["code"];
            }
        return $allNosolog;
    }
```

Comment: Понадобится стек или эмулирующий его список.

Comment: мне нужно в ширину проходится. Там вроде бы очередь нужна. Я примерно понимаю как это работает, но реализовать не получается

Comment: Без собственного кода говорить пока не о чем. Отредактируйте вопрос, показав свои попытки, пока не заминусовали.

Comment: 1)У меня есть корень дерева с вершиной 2. 
2)Пока дочерний элемент не равен NUll.
3)Проходим по родительским элементам. Их может быть несколько, поэтому цикл foreach.
4)Каждый родительский элемент обрабатываем функцией cicleFree. Он нам достанет дочерние элементы этого родителя и записываем эти элементы в $massive.(Проблемма что я не могу задать правильный путь в массиве, куда записывать элементы)
5)Проходим по найденым дочерним элементам и на основе их формируем массив и записываем его как родительский чтобы по нему пройтись и узнать дочерние его элементы.

Comment: Незнаю как написать лучше и понятнее, проект большой, а опыта в алгаритмах да и в ООП нету. Думаю сегодня уже увольнятся, моих знаний не достаточно(

Comment: Как это родительских несколько? В дереве такого не бывает

Comment: я не правильны выразился. Я читаю теорию и там показано как перебирают дерево сперва слева, потом справа. У меня выходит так что дерево читается по уровням.

Answer (score 0):

Обход бинарного дерева по уровням с использованием очереди:

```
//начали с корня
queue.insert(root);

while (queue is not empty) {
   node = queue.extract;

   обработать node;

   if (node.left <> Nil)
       queue.insert(node.left);

   if (node.right <> Nil)
       queue.insert(node.right);
}
```